# Type '{ onAddEvent: (event: any) => Promise<void>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: react-typescript

I'm trying to convert my code from ReactJs to ReactTypescript.
I'm trying to create an event by using user input information in a form.  But when I trying to add event to database it give this error:

Here is my code:

```
 return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <EventForm onAddEvent={addEventHandler} />
    </React.Fragment>
 );
```

The error is Type '{ onAddEvent: (event: any) => Promise<void>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'onAddEvent' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)

```
return (
    <div className='new-event'>
      <EventForm onSaveEventData={saveEventDataHandler}/>
    </div>
  );
```

The error is Type '{ onSaveEventData: (enteredEventData: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'onSaveEventData' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)

I am new to typescript, Any suggestion, please?

Expecting to read user input then create new event in the database

Comment: reminder: if your question has been answered make sure to accept or mark it as answered so others know it is completed!

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you pass a function without typing that specific function and can be solved with creating a type for the component, I'm not sure what your function looks like so I made an example function for onSaveData but you can replace it with your own (or show me the complete code and ill update it for you).

Below is a snippet of the code but [you can also see it in action and fork it in code sandbox by clicking here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/simple-stackoverflow-example-trw39g?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqou7cke00063b6kglv8jvms%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqou7ckd00023b6kafbd158t%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqou7ckd00033b6k457gbocg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqou7cke00053b6kr675mdgc%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqou7ckd00023b6kafbd158t%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqou7ckd00013b6kuoqasrrf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqou7ckd00023b6kafbd158t%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqou7ckd00013b6kuoqasrrf%2522%257D%252C%2522clqou7cke00053b6kr675mdgc%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqou7ckd00043b6ki9f2384f%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqou7cke00053b6kr675mdgc%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqou7ckd00043b6ki9f2384f%2522%257D%252C%2522clqou7ckd00033b6k457gbocg%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqou7ckd00033b6k457gbocg%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

```
type EventFormProps = {
  onSaveEventData: () => void;
};

const EventForm = ({ onSaveEventData }: EventFormProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="button" onClick={onSaveEventData}>
      Click Me
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const saveEventDataHandler = () => {
    console.log("do some logic here");
    alert("button Clicked");
  };

  return (
    <div className="new-event">
      <EventForm onSaveEventData={saveEventDataHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

if you provide the full event form code as well as the full code for how you're trying to use it, I will create a new example that uses your props.